# What is the maximum number of elements an enum can have in C?

Tags: c, enums

I already have around 10 elements in enum which I am using. I wanted to know the maximum so that I could code properly.

Comment: You really should not be worried about the maximal number of enums to use. My guess is that it is somewhere in the range of `INT_MAX`. which means *a lot*.

Comment: @Mat this question is not duplicate. Here op ask for maximum number of element in enum where your link is about the size of enum elemnt..!! isnt it??

Comment: @Mr.32: yes, you're right. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Constantinius what do you mean by maximal number of enums to use..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `enum` can hold at least `1023` enumeration constants in a conforming implementation (*see §5.2.4.1 "Translation limits" of ISO/IEC 9899:1999*). So that gives you a lower bound.

Since the type of an enumeration constant is `int` (*see §6.4.4.3 "Enumeration constants" of ISO/IEC 9899:1999*), the upper bound would be `INT_MAX + 1` (assuming no duplicate enumeration constant values), or even `INT_MAX + 1 - INT_MIN` if you also use negative values.

Any implementation is free to choose how many enumeration constants an enumeration can contain, as long as it's between these lower and upper bounds.

Comment: +1 just for explaning both things 1> for maximum number of elemnt in enum and 2>size of each elemnt in enum and maxim number can be stored by each element..!!!

Comment: Negative values are not usable unless you explicitly assign values. The language standard specifies that successive enumeration constants each increase in value by 1, so the negative values are not otherwise reachable.

Comment: @R. : sensible comment - integrated it into the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about identifiers in a enumerator list? Enums are int constants, how many int constants can you have? *Rhetoric question*

Comment: `enum foo {AAA = 0, BBB = 0, CCC = 0, DDD = 0};`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, from c99 standard draft 6.7.2.2 #3 `(The use of enumerators with = may produce enumeration constants with values that duplicate other values in the same enumeration.)`

Comment: You can only have so many int constants ... but you can have many more names for them :)

Answer (score 0):

The op wants to know the number of elements in an enum structure.  To do coding "properly" then use the size definitions for the toolchain, usually in <limits.h>, although INT_MAX may be signed int.  For example if the limitation is an unsigned integer, then for an 8-bit implementations usually would use 16bit enum and could contain up to 65536 elements.